# How to use a parameter with optional type in an optional protocol method

Tags: ios, swift3, optional-parameters

```
@objc protocol filterDelegate {
    @objc optional func appliedFilters(_ filters:[String:AnyObject], withDisplayValues displayValues:[String?]) -> Void
}
```

The above protocol method gives me an error *Method cannot be marked @objc because the type of the parameter 2 cannot be represented in Objective-C*

I know this error is due to usage of String? with @objc.

How can I achieve the same functionality of passing String? to an optional protocol method. Is there an alternative for the same?

Comment: Will you use this protocol in Objective C code?

Answer (score 0):

`String` data type support only in Swift. So you can use `NSString` rather than `String`, which support on both platform.

```
@objc protocol filterDelegate {
    @objc optional func appliedFilters(_ filters:[String:AnyObject], withDisplayValues displayValues:[NSString?]) -> Void
}
```